# argv[1] giving segfaults

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, argv

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(strcmp(argv[1],"-e")==0)
  { 
    //perform code
  }

  //code if argv[1] is not "-e"

return 0;
}
```

When I take out the whole if statement:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "-e")==0)
```

my code if strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0) is not "-e" works fine. But when I leave it in, my code only works for when the if statement above produces true. Any ideas on why this may happen? For example:

If I compile with argv[1] not commented out:

//example program will be an executable

exampleProgram -e < a.txt works but exampleProgram < a.txt doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, if you don't send any argument to the program then `args[1]` doesn't exist and you are trying to access to an unassigned memory position.

You may do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1],"-e")==0)
  { 
    //perform code
  }

  //code if argv[1] is not "-e"

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

argv is an array. When you try to index into array beyond last element you get segfault. To not go past the last element check the value of argc, and argc - 1 will be the index of the last element you can access. More on segfaults here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Answer (score 0):

the reason
`exampleProgram -e < a.txt` works and 
`exampleProgram < a.txt` doesn't
is because when there is no argument being passed into the program, where is no `argv[1]`, it is out of bounds of the args array. what you need to do before testing `argv[1]` is test to see if there are that many arguments to begin with.

For example:

```
if (argc > 1) {
  if(strcmp(argv[1],"-e")==0) {

  }
}
```

`argc` is used to hold how many arguments exist in the program so you can test this before going out of bounds.